# Getting Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am trying to implement search functionality in Node, mongoose.
There is two parameter I like to search upon, either by name or artist. If any of the two matches with the current database it should return value(making it restful)

However, it is sending response `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`
and `Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated`    and even the response which i am getting is empty

I am trying to execute two queries in it, which i think might be the problem. How should i write it, or what is a correct way to write these type of functionality

Here is my current code

`app.get('/search/:textValue', controller.findData)`

and the findData

```
exports.findData = (req, res)=>{

    const searchParam = req.params.textValue;
    let storeResult = []
    if(searchParam==null|| searchParam == undefined || searchParam==""){
        return res.status(500).json("Send a valid input")
     }
  else{
        Song.find({artists: new RegExp(searchParam, "i")}).lean().then((data)=>{
            storeResult[0].push(data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            return res.send(err)
        })

        Song.find({name: new RegExp(searchParam, "i")}).lean().then((data)=>{
            storeResult[1].push(data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            return res.send(err)
        })

        return res.send(storeResult)
    }
}
```

They are working for single queries perfectly fine, what changes should be made over here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it you're using `res.send(storeResult)` before you fill in `storeResult`. How so? You fill it in with your `.then()` callbacks, which haven't yet been invoked.

Try chaining your `then` callbacks.

```
 Song.find({artists: new RegExp(searchParam, "i")}).lean()
.then((data)=>{
    storeResult.push(data);
})
.then(() => {
    Song.find({name: new RegExp(searchParam, "i")}).lean()
    .then((data)=>{

        storeResult.push(data)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(storeResult)
        res.send(storeResult)
    })  
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Here is error")
    console.log(err)
    res.send(err)
})
}
```

Hint. Step-into in your debugger is useful for troubleshooting this kind of code.

Comment: sorry my bad, i forget about async behavior :-(

Comment: Thankx for ur help,However,I tried using ur code, there was some brackets missing, and i ultimatley ended up having a nested promise

Comment: Sorry for the typos.  Thanks for fixing them.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it was stupid of me to forget the async behavior

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
exports.findData = (req, res)=>{
    let count=0;
    const searchParam = req.params.textValue;
    let storeResult = []
    if(searchParam==null|| searchParam == undefined || searchParam==""){
        return res.status(500).json("Send a valid input")
     }
  else{
        Song.find({artists: new RegExp(searchParam, "i")}).lean().then((data)=>{
            storeResult[0].push(data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            count++;
            return res.send(err)
        })
        if(count == 0) {
            Song.find({name: new RegExp(searchParam, "i")}).lean().then((data)=>{
                storeResult[1].push(data)
            }).catch((err)=>{
                count++;
                return res.send(err)
            })
        }
        if(count == 0) {
            return res.send(storeResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

1. You're starting with empty array `let storeResult = []`
2. Then you access its first element (which does not exist)  `storeResult[0].push(data)`
3. This will trigger your `catch` callback. And then do a `res.send(err)`
4. Even if you called `return` it will still continue in `(req, res) => {}` . This is because the `return` is only for the `(err) => { // }` callback
5. Same thing with `storeResult[1].push(data)`
6. Finally you call `return res.send(storeResult)` which effectively finishes your `(req, res) => {}` callback and return another response to the client

**Solution**:

When you push to your `storeResult` array, omit the index. Like this

```
storeResult.push(data)
```

**Note**

Even when pushing correctly, an error might happen while accessing the database. This is why you **also** need to chain your callbacks like [*O. Jones* answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840898/getting-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent/54841202#54841202)